# Reactjs Parent not getting child data change values. Rerender issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

**I need to update Parent table when data is changed from child edit form. Not getting the updated data in parent component.
I'm passing the data using all the passible ways as per my understanding. I'm not much experienced in react. So it would be really very helpful if someone can help me to understand where i'm making mistake.**

**PARENT Component is class component-**

```
import Radium from 'radium';
import Dock from 'react-dock';
import {Divider} from '@material-ui/core';
import "react-tabulator/lib/styles.css"; 
import "react-tabulator/css/bootstrap/tabulator_bootstrap.min.css";
import { React15Tabulator, reactFormatter, MultiValueFormatter } from "react-tabulator";
import {Badge, Row, Button, Col,Card} from 'react-bootstrap';

import EditServer from '../EditServer';
import Confirm from '../../../ui-components/Confirm';
// import './index.scss';
import jsondata from '../../../constants/data/json/ApplicationServer.json';



const styles = {
  root: {
    fontSize: '16px',
    color: '#999',
    height: '100vh',
  },
  main: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: '30vh',
  },
  dockContent: {
    // width: '400px',
     height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'left',
    padding:'1rem',
    overflowX:"hidden",
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  remove: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
    right: '10px',
    top: '10px',
    cursor: 'pointer'
  }
}

const positions = ['left', 'top', 'right', 'bottom'];
const dimModes = ['transparent', 'none', 'opaque'];
// const dimStyle = ['all']

function SimpleBage (props: any) {
  const rowData = props.cell._cell.row.data;
  const cellValue = props.cell._cell.value || 'STANDALONE | DOWN | PRIMARY | BACKUP';
  if(cellValue === 'STANDALONE'){
    return <h5><Badge pill variant="warning" className="btn-size"
     onClick={() => alert(rowData.serverStatus)}>
    {cellValue}</Badge></h5>;
  }
  else if(cellValue === 'DOWN'){
    return <h5><Badge pill variant="dark" className="btn-size">
    {cellValue}</Badge></h5>;
  }
  else if(cellValue === 'PRIMARY'){
    return <h5><Badge pill variant="success" className="btn-size">
    {cellValue}</Badge></h5>;
  }
  else if(cellValue === 'BACKUP'){
    return <h5><Badge pill variant="primary" className="btn-size">
    {cellValue}</Badge></h5>;
  }
  else if(cellValue === 'STANDBY'){
    return <h5><Badge pill variant="secondary" className="btn-size">
    {cellValue}</Badge></h5>;
  }

}
const editableColumns = [
  {
    title: "#",
    field: "index",
    width: 80,
    dir:"asc",
    // headerFilter: "input"
  },
  {
    title: "Server Name",
    field: "serverName",
    hozAlign: "left",
    dir:"asc",
  },
  {
    title: "Server Status",
    field: "serverStatus",
    // width: 100,
    hozAlign: 'left', 
    //formatter: MultiValueFormatter,
    formatter: reactFormatter(<SimpleBage />),
  },
  {
    title: "Server Group",
    field: "serverGroup",
    hozAlign: "left",
  },
] 
  let data = [...jsondata];
  const serverListArray =localStorage.getItem("configuration");


class ApplicationServer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
  this.state = {
   data: data, 
   rowSelection:"",  
   stopBtnVisible:false,
   startBtnVisble:true,
   selectedServerName: "",
   selectedServerGroup:"",
   selectedServerStatus:"",
   selectedServerStatusChange:this.state,
   positionIdx: 2,
   dimModeIdx: "transparent",
   isVisible: false,
   fluid: true,
   customAnimation: true,
   slow: true,
   size: 0.30,      
  isServerStarted:this.state,
  serverName:null,
  rowIndex:null,    
   };
 
this.handleVisibleChange = this.handleVisibleChange.bind(this);
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.onClose= this.onClose.bind(this);
}
ref = null;
onClose = isVisible =>{
this.setState({ isVisible: false }); 
} 




clearData = () => {
this.setState({ data: [] });
};



handleChange = (handler) =>{
  // console.log("update handler data", serverGroup)  
  // const updatedServerGroup = event.target.value;
 // console.log("handle form submit in table", this.state.selectedServerGroup, this.props.serverGroup);
 console.log("handle form submit in table", handler);
 this.setState({
   ...handler
   //selectedServerGroup:handler.target.serverGroup
})
//console.log("handle form submit in table", this.state);
console.log("handle form submit in table", handler);
}



render(){ 
  
 const options = {
  height: 215,
  movableRows: true,
  history: true,
  movableColumns: true,
  resizableRows: true ,
  reactiveData:true,
 };
 const duration = this.state.slow ? 1000 : 100;
 const dur = duration / 1000;
 const transitions = ['left', 'top', 'width', 'height']
  .map(p => `${p} ${dur}s cubic-bezier(0, 1.5, 0.5, 1)`)
  .join(',');
  console.log("Render data:", serverListArray);
  if(Array.isArray(serverListArray) && serverListArray.length>0){
    data=[...serverListArray];
    //jsondata= serverListArray;
    }
return(
 <div style={[styles.root]}>
  <div style={{
            position: 'relative',
            height: 'calc(100vh - 50px)',
        }}>
   
 <Row className="table-control-bar">
      <Col sm={8}><h5>Server Controls</h5></Col>

      <Col sm={4} className="text-right">
      <Button variant={this.state.failoverButtonVariant} 
        className="mr-2" 
       id="serverFailover"
      onClick={this.handleServerFailover}
       selectedserverName={this.selectedserverName}
        disabled={this.state.failoverButtonDisabled}>Failover</Button>
      <Button variant={this.state.editButtonVariant}  
        className="mr-2"
        id="serverEdit"
        selectedServerName={this.selectedServerName} 
        disabled={this.state.editButtonDisabled}
        onClick={this.handleVisibleChange}>Edit</Button>
      {this.state.stopBtnVisible === false &&
     (
      <Button
      onClick={this.handleServerStart}
      className="mr-2"
      id="serverStart"
      selectedserverName={this.selectedserverName}
      visible={this.state.startBtnVisible}
      variant={this.state.startButtonVariant} 
      disabled={this.state.startButtonDisabled}>Start
       </Button>   
      )}   
     {this.state.startBtnVisible === false &&
     (<Button  onClick={this.handleServerStop}
      className="mr-2"
      id="serverStop"
      selectedserverName={this.selectedserverName}
      variant="primary">Stop</Button>)}
        <Button variant={this.state.restartButtonVariant}
         id="serverRestart"  
        onClick={this.handleServerRestart}
         selectedserverName={this.selectedserverName}
        disabled={this.state.restartButtonDisabled}>Restart</Button>
        </Col>
    </Row>
  
  <div>
     <React15Tabulator
    columns={editableColumns}
    data={data}
    selectable={1}
    rowClick={this.rowClick}
    options={options}
    data-custom-attr="test-custom-attribute"
    className={"custom-css-class" + this.state.rowSelection}
    tooltips={true}
    layout={"fitData"}
    />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
<Dock position={positions[this.state.positionIdx]} 
              size={this.state.size}
              dimMode={dimModes[this.state.dimModeIdx]}
              isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
              onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
              fluid={this.state.fluid}
              dimStyle={{ background: 'rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.2)'}, {pointerEvents:'all !important'}}             
              dockStyle={this.state.customAnimation ? { transition: transitions } : null, {top:'6%'} }
              //  ,{top:'13%'}              
              dockHiddenStyle={this.state.customAnimation ? {
                transition: [transitions, `opacity 0.01s linear ${dur}s`].join(',')
              } : null}
              duration={duration}>
          {({ position, isResizing }) =>
            <div style={[styles.dockContent]} className="modal-container">
              <h4>Edit Server Group</h4>
              <Divider />
              <EditServer
               handleInputChange={this.handleChange} 
              //  handleChange = {e => console.log(e)}            
               serverName={this.state.selectedServerName}
               serverGroup= {this.state.selectedServerGroup}
               onClose={this.onClose} />
              <span onClick={() => this.setState({ isVisible: false })}
                         style={styles.remove} title="close">&#10006;</span>
              </div>
              }
        </Dock>
        </div>
</div>
)
    }
    handleSizeChange = size => {
      this.setState({ size });
   } 
}



export default ApplicationServer = Radium(ApplicationServer);
```

**CHILD Component is functional component-**

```
import {func, string} from 'prop-types';
import {makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import {Row, Col, Button, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';
import toast from '../../../ui-components/Toaster';
import Input from '../../../ui-components/Input';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        '& > *': {
          margin: theme.spacing(2),
        },
      },
    formControl: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      minWidth: 120,
      maxWidth: 300,
    },
    chips: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    chip: {
      margin: 2,
    },
    noLabel: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
  }));

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
    return {
      fontWeight:
        personName.indexOf(name) === -1
          ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
          : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
    };
  }

export default function EditServer(props) {
  const {onClose} = props;
  let serverGroup = props.serverGroup;
  const initialFormState = { 
     id: null,
     serverName: props.serverName,
     serverGroup: props.serverGroup,
     saveDisabled: true,
     cancelDisabled:true,
     showDockModal:false,
     edited:false,
     }
    // console.log("inside child", initialFormState);
const [handler, setHandler] = useState();
  //const ref = useRef(null);
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    //event.preventDefault();
    console.log("edit server props input change", handler);
    let { name, value } = event.target;  
    //handler.serverGroup = event.target.value;
    setHandler({...handler, [name]: value, edited:true});
  console.log("inside edit form change:", handler, value, name);
  }

const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
  //console.log('inside handleFormSubmit', event, props);
  event.preventDefault();
  onClose();
  if (handler.edited){       
   //let newServerGroup=  handler.serverGroup;
    //console.log("form submit", handler);    
    setHandler({
      ...handler,      
       edited:false,       
      });   
      console.log("inside edit form change:", handler, event)
      // props.serverGroup=newServerGroup;
      // return handleInputChange(handler.serverGroup.value);
   return toast.success(initialFormState.serverGroup + " Server Group Changed to SIMULATION !");
}
}


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <Form className="scrollY"
    onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
    >
    <Row>
        <Col sm={4} className="text-align-right">
        <label htmlFor="serverName">Server Name<span className="red">*</span></label>
        </Col>
        <Col sm={8}>
        <Input
        type="text"
          required
          id="severName"
          name="severName"
          // label="Handler Name"
          fullWidth
          autoComplete="given-name"
          value={initialFormState.serverName}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          disabled="true"

        />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col sm={4} className="text-align-right">
        <label htmlFor="serverGroup" required>Server Group<span className="red">*</span></label>
        </Col>
        <Col sm={8}>
      <Input
        type="string"
          required
          id="serverGroup"
          name="serverGroup"
          // label="Handler Speed"
          fullWidth
          autoComplete="family-name"
          defaultValue={initialFormState.serverGroup}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          
        />
        </Col>
      </Row>     
     
      <Row>
       <Col sm={4}>
        {/*  <Button variant="secondary" disabled className="btn-custom" onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>*/}
        </Col> 
    <Col sm={8}>
       <Button type="submit"
         variant="primary"
          className="btn-custom"
      
          >
          Submit
          </Button> 
    </Col>
    
    </Row>       
    </Form>
  </React.Fragment>
);
}

EditServer.propTypes = {
  onSuccess: func,
};
```

I'm using react tabulator.
Appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: In Child- 

```const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    //event.preventDefault();
    console.log("edit server props input change", handler);
    let { name, value } = event.target;  
    //handler.serverGroup = event.target.value;
    setHandler({...handler, [name]: value, edited:true});
  console.log("inside edit form change:", handler, value, name);
  }```

Comment: In Parent- 
```handleChange = (handler) =>{
  // console.log("update handler data", serverGroup)  
  // const updatedServerGroup = event.target.value;
 // console.log("handle form submit in table", this.state.selectedServerGroup, this.props.serverGroup);
 console.log("handle form submit in table", handler);
 this.setState({
   data:[...handler]
   //selectedServerGroup:handler.target.serverGroup
})
//console.log("handle form submit in table", this.state);
console.log("handle form submit in table", data);
}```

Comment: And child component in Parent -

 <EditServer
               handleInputChange={this.handleChange} 
              //  handleChange = {e => console.log(e)}            
               serverName={this.state.selectedServerName}
               serverGroup= {this.state.selectedServerGroup}
               onClose={this.onClose} />